# Java syntax highlighting for the java-8 tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

Java 8 will gain a lot of traction pretty soon on Stack Overflow, as people will have lots of questions about lambdas, default methods, and the new [streams-api](/questions/tagged/streams-api). I think it's worth adding [java](/questions/tagged/java) syntax highlighting to questions tagged as  [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8). Probably other Java versions are affected as well. An example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17462090/521799

Comment: Do we want to encourage people to omit the java tag?

Comment: I think your concern is unrelated. People usually don't tag questions with [tag:java] just to turn on syntax highlighting. Au contraire. They may already have five tags, and they may find [tag:java-8] more important than [tag:java]

Comment: I fear those people may be acting unwisely, I certainly don't have java-8 in my favourite tags, nor do I search for it... ever. And yet I have answered questions specific to java-8 because they were correctly tagged java. If you don't tag your java question as java you are basically throwing it into a black hole

Comment: I can see your point. I guess this discussion is the same as always, when handling versions in tags... Nonetheless, I still think that the concern is unrelated. If there is a [tag:java-8] tag, then it is a clear indicator for Java syntax highlighting, regardless of the presence of a [tag:java] tag